# Automatically adjust jquery colorbox height

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have collapsable content within a colorbox popup.

I set width to 'auto' which works for automatic width however how about automatic height? For example when the colorbox pops up, it fits the first image however when I click the image for the second collapsable image, the window doesn't resize. Is this possible?

HTML

```
<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content"><img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/find-scheme.png" alt="find your scheme" /></a></p>

<div style='display:none'>
        <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
        <div class="two-step">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/2-step-sfinder.png" width="990" height="100"  class="show_hide" alt="3 steps" /></a>
</div>

<div class="slidingDiv">
<img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/step1.png" width="60" height="58" class="show_hide" alt="step 1" />
<font color=white><strong><h3>I want my employment status to be:</h3></strong></font> <a href="#"  class="show_hide"></a>
<div id="question_1">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/umbrella-emp.png" style="margin-left:80px;" width="300" height="118" class="first_s"  alt="umbrella employee" />    </a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/images/self-employed.png" style="margin-left:170px;" width="300"  height="118" class="second_s" alt="self employed" />   </a>
</div>
</div>
</div
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
                $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
                $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
                $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none",  width:"75%", height:"75%"});
                $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
                $(".ajax").colorbox();
                $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640,  innerHeight:390});
                $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500,  innerHeight:409});
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%",  height:"80%"});
                $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"auto"});
                $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                    onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to  open'); },
                    onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started  to load the targeted content'); },
                    onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has  displayed the loaded content'); },
                    onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has  begun the close process'); },
                    onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has  completely closed'); }
                });

                $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
                $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none',  retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});

                //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
                $("#click").click(function(){ 
                    $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00",  "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still  be here.");
                    return false;
                });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // at first hide divs
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv2").hide(); 
        $(".slidingDiv3").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv4").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv5").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv6").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv7").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv8").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv9").hide();
        $(".slidingDiv10").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
    $('.first_s').live('click', function(){
       $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    })
    $('.second_s').live('click', function(){
        $(".slidingDiv3").slideToggle();
    })  
    $('.third_s').live('click', function(){
        $(".slidingDiv4").slideToggle();
    }) 
    $('.fourth_s').live('click', function(){
        $(".slidingDiv5").slideToggle();
    }) 
    $('.fifth_s').live('click', function(){
        $(".slidingDiv6").slideToggle();
    })  
    $('.sixth_s').live('click', function(){
        $(".slidingDiv7").slideToggle();
    })  
    $('.seventh_s').live('click', function(){
        $(".slidingDiv8").slideToggle();
    })   
    $('.eighth_s').live('click', function(){
       $(".slidingDiv9").slideToggle();
    })   
    $('.ninth_s').live('click', function(){
        $(".slidingDiv10").slideToggle();
    }) 
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kuaet/37/)

Answer (score 0):

Look this complete solution, it work perfectly.**=>** [**FIDDLE (new)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kuaet/72/)

Here, a script adjust the margin-top to center the content.

You can show multiple steps with `<a goToStep="2">...</a>` and `<div step="2">...</div>` and hide other multiple steps with `<a closeStep="2">...</a>` , that's really simple to use...
You can do all things at the same time `<a goToStep="4,5" closeStep="1,3">...</a>`

For responsive colorbox, you can do it with maxWidth :

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', maxWidth:'100%'});
```

All is in the fiddle..

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, is it possible to update my jsfiddle with your recommendations as I'm not sure where the second part goes http://jsfiddle.net/Kuaet/37/

Comment: I am using the inline option by the way, not iframe

Comment: I've completely removed my javascript and replaced with yours, now I don't even get the popupbox? http://jsfiddle.net/Kuaet/47/

Comment: To explain, when the popupbox comes up wit with blue image, the box is set to width:auto therefore resizes to the width of the image but it doesn;t do the same with the height. The height seems to be fixed and when I open an expandable box (by clicking the blue image) the height doesn't change. What I want to happen is for the colorbox popup to adjust so it always fits around the content.

Comment: This is a good solution but I really need my idea to stand with the box popping up and the background greyed out as it needs to be prominent on the screen. Is there no way of taking my idea http://jsfiddle.net/Kuaet/37/ and making the height responsive?

Comment: Ok, here is a screenshot of how I would expect it to look http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/images/colorbox.png It is the height I want responsive, currently when you click the blue image I want the whole box to expand to match the content (as per the screenshot) but currently it just adds a scroll bar on the right and you need to scroll down to see the rest of the content.

Comment: I think a good way of explaining this is that I have hidden content that appears once each image is clicked with the first image to click being the blue image. What I want to happen is once the hidden content appears, the outside box (with the blue border) grows to go along with the content so at any point the whole box displays all the content within.

Comment: I fixed this by working around it. I simply made the outer div the maximum height all the divs gro to and made all the box/background transparent so it has the look as if the box is expanding as you click.